# ChartJS: Remove padding on first and last bars on Barchart

Tags: chart.js

I am trying to fit a barchart to the parent container, but there either is a gap to the left and right side of the container (see example) or, with offset: false, the first and the last bar are only half the width of all other bars... how to fix this?

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    // The type of chart we want to create
    type: 'bar',

    // The data for our dataset
    data: {
        labels: ['one','two','three','four','five'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'My First dataset',
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            data: [100, 90, 80, 90, 100],
        }]
    },

    // Configuration options go here
    options: {
      legend:{display:false},
               scales: {
                        xAxes: [
                            {
                              display: false,
                              offset: true,
                            },
                        ],
                        yAxes: [
                            {
                                display: false,
                                offset: false,
                                ticks: {
                                  beginAtZero: true
                                }
                            },
                        ],
                    },
    }
});
```

```css
div {
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:0;
  margin:0
}

#myChart {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<div>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by defining left and right invisible border for each bar individually using the [`borderWidth`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#borderwidth) option on the dataset. At the same time you need to define `categoryPercentage: 1` and `barPercentage: 1` on the dataset (see [Dataset Configuration](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#dataset-configuration)).

In below code sample, the computed `borderWidths` results in the following array:

```
[
  {
    "left": 0,
    "right": 20
  },
  {
    "left": 5,
    "right": 15
  },
  {
    "left": 10,
    "right": 10
  },
  {
    "left": 15,
    "right": 5
  },
  {
    "left": 20,
    "right": 0
  }
]
```

Change the value of the variable `factor` if you want to change the gap between bars.

```js
var labels = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'];

var borderWidths = [];
var factor = 5;
for (let i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
  borderWidths.push({ left: i * factor, right: (labels.length - 1 - i) * factor });
}

var chart = new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My First dataset',
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      data: [100, 90, 80, 90, 100],
      categoryPercentage: 1,
      barPercentage: 1,
      borderWidth: borderWidths,
      borderColor: 'white',
      hoverBorderColor: 'white'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        display: false
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        display: false,
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }],
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#div_chart {
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:0;
  margin:0
}

#myChart {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<div id="div_chart">
   <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: While this example surely works, I am open to other suggestions as borders seem to produce artifacts as of 2.9.3 - its already on the roadmap for 3.0, but nonetheless, if there is another way to accomplish fitting a barchart to the edges of the parent, feeld free to add to this thread. Pen: https://codepen.io/rx2347/pen/MWwaodE